# como coloco o background na tela inteira, CSS?

Tags: html, css

A imagem não pega a tela toda, já tentei colocar `width` e `height`, mas continuou da mesma forma a imagem aparece na página.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title> Vidas Secas </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="3.jpg">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url(1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho da imagem? Já que no CSS está `no-repeat`? Width e height não funcionam com background

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece pois você está setando o valor `no-repeat` na propriedade `background-repeat`, troque o valor por `repeat`

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6a5ce13734910d828649760622ac35e5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu CSS está quase certo. Falta usar a propriedade `background-size` para definir como o background vai ocupar o espaço. Vc ainda pode usar o `background-position` se quiser centralizar o `background` no meio do elemento onde ele está definido.

Veja como fica com o background ocupando o `body` inteiro, mas sem repetir a imagem:

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/300/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

- Aqui tem um link didático com alguns exemplos práticos e com as propriedades do background explicadas de forma fácil https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade `background` possui uma série de opções para serem definidas, como [background-position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp), [background-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) e uma que pode te ajudar, caso não queira que a imagem fique repetindo em seu elemento mas que mesmo assim ocupe a tela inteira, seria a propriedade [background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), com ela você pode definir como `background-position: cover` que ocupará todo o elemento em questão.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar *background-size: 100%*.