# Background CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Não há alguma forma de esticar o brackground de forma a ocupar a web toda? A foto que estou a usar tem a seguinte resolução :1024 × 640. Quando a meto como background ela fica com uma barra branca do lado direito. Há alguma solução para este problema? Obrigado

Código:

```css
td, div{

  color : #FFFFFF;
  }
body  {
  background-image: url ("background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

}
```

```html
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  
 <audio id="sound_button">
      <source src="button.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <audio id="sound_music">
      <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

 
    </head>
<body>
  <center>
  
  <input type="button" value="rewind" onclick="rewind()">
  <input type="button" id="music_state" value="play" onclick="change_music()">
   


<table width="10">
    <tr>
        <td >Linhas: </td><td><input type="text" id="txt_linhas" size="4" value="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Colunas:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt_colunas" size="4" value="5"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Desenha tabuleiro" onclick="pede_desenha_tabuleiro()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="tabuleiro" >Aqui vai aparecer o tabuleiro.</div>
<span id="info_jogador" style="visibility: hidden">Jogador: <span id="jogador">1</span></span>
```

Comment: Talvez vc esteja procurando por `background-size: cover;`. Mas sem os códigos do que vc está fazendo fica difícil dar uma resposta mais precisa.

Comment: Tenho esses códigos. A imagem que eu tenho ocupa metade do ecrã, e eu queria que ela ocupasse todo. Sabes se isso é possivél? Coloquei esse código e não mudou nada. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @GonçaloSousa sua resposta está aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299083/97477 veja o CSS com atenção, principalmente o background-size e também repare que o elemento que o background está tem que ter 100% de largura e altura do ecrã

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não era esse o problema. A imagem continua nem estar ajustada ao ecrã, e nem sequer centraliza. Não consigo entender o porquê

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, coloque seu código HTML e CSS, assim podemos votar para reabri-la, Sem o seu código não tem como te responder, já que a outra resposta não resolveu o problema

Comment: Já editei a pergunta coloquei todo o código, menos o script, pois não achei necessário. Acho que agora ficará mais fácil. Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Creio eu que você tem que tirar esse `background-size:100%`, pois já definiu como `background-size:cover`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas mesmo assim o programa não está a fazer o que eu quero. Vou tentar pedir ajuda ao meu professor amanhã, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Cara seu background simplesmente não aplica corretamente pq vc escreveu a propriedade `background-image` errado. no seu código está assim: `url ("background.png")` repare que vc deixou um espaço entre e o parenteses `url ()`, não deve haver esse espaço, tem que ser `url()` tudo junto. Outro detalhe é que vc não colocou um tamanho também para o `HTML`. O `body` herda a altura do pai, no caso o pai do `body` é o `html`, então vc tb precisa definir uma altura para ele nesse caso.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
td, div{
  color : #FFFFFF;
}
body  {
  background-image: url("https://placecage.com/100/100");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-size: 100%;  não precisa disso */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="rewind" onclick="rewind()">
<input type="button" id="music_state" value="play" onclick="change_music()">

<table width="10">
    <tr>
        <td >Linhas: </td><td><input type="text" id="txt_linhas" size="4" value="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Colunas:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt_colunas" size="4" value="5"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Desenha tabuleiro" onclick="pede_desenha_tabuleiro()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="tabuleiro" >Aqui vai aparecer o tabuleiro.</div>
<span id="info_jogador" style="visibility: hidden">Jogador: <span id="jogador">1</span></span>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas mesmo assim o programa não está a fazer o que eu quero. Vou tentar pedir ajuda ao meu professor amanhã, obrigado.

Comment: @GonçaloSousa sem problemas, se vc me der mais detalhes tb posso ajudar a esclarecer ai a situação... Veja que aqui funciona perfeitamente, então não há motivo para não estar funcionando ai também

Comment: Muito obrigado já descobri o erro. Já está direitinho como eu quero. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o background-attachment: fixed;
em alguns casos você consegue ocupar toda screen mas a imagem fica fixa.

Comment: Já consegui resolver esse problema, obrigado pela ajuda